# storage_client.create_bucket Insufficient Permission

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-storage

I am following the guidelines in google cloud's documentation here:

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/moving-buckets#storage-create-bucket-python

and when I run the code to create a bucket I get the following error:

> Forbidden: 403 POST https://storage.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b?: Insufficient Permission

What can be possibly wrong? Where should I go and resolve the permission?

Answer (score 0):

Before following that doc, make sure to [Set up authentication](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries#setting_up_authentication) for your Client library. This includes:

- Create a service account and its key.
- Set it as a Environment variable in your Operative System.

Even if you are running the script from a Cloud Shell, this Environment variable needs to be set.

Keep in mind that the Service Account will have the Owner role, which has the permissions to create buckets **but** for additional interactions, such as upload or delete files to your bucket the account will require some extra roles like Storage Admin.

Hope this is helpful! :)

Answer (score 0):

1.Create a service account

```
gcloud iam service-accounts create [SA-NAME] \
--description "[SA-DESCRIPTION]" \
--display-name "[SA-DISPLAY-NAME]"
```

2.Get the name of your service account just created:

```
gcloud iam service-account list
```

3.Grant the storage admin role to the service account

```
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding my-project-123 \
--member serviceAccount:my-sa-123@my-project-123.iam.gserviceaccount.com \
--role roles/storage.admin
```

4.Create a service account key

```
gcloud iam service-accounts keys create ~/key.json \
--iam-account [SA-NAME]@[PROJECT-ID].iam.gserviceaccount.com
```

5.Set the env variable

```
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="/home/user/Downloads/[FILE_NAME].json"
```

6.Run the code from the tutorial

Comment: I'm using a docker container so I don't have "/home/user/Downloads/" on my machine. Can it be stored somewhere else?

Comment: you can use the [Secret Manager documentation](https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager/docs)